# How to make Retrofit deserialize response to null object when the returned type is not matching the expected?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

**Retrofit is not deserialising correctly**. Because I don't have control over backend I need my code to adapt to it, **I need Retrofit to deserialize response to null** when it isn't the right type. Instead it creates the object but with null value members. So **instead of returning null it returns DefaultResponseResult(success=null, action=null, res=null)**

This is my method (I tried fixing it with ? at Call<DefaultResponseResult?>):

```
@PUT("/SOMETHING/fcmtoken/")
fun registerFCMToken(@Query("fcmToken") fcmToken: String, @Query("driverID") driverID: String, @Query("dtoken") dtoken: String): Call<DefaultResponseResult?>
```

and in client file:

```
fun <T> fetch(requestCall: Call<T?>, completion: ((Result<T, Exception>) -> Unit)) {
        requestCall.enqueue(object: Callback<T?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<T?>, response: Response<T?>) {
                val responseData = response.body()
                var errorLog: ErrorLog? = response.errorBody()?.let { gson.fromJson(it.charStream(), ErrorLog::class.java) }
                
                //FOR SOME REASON RESPONSE DATA IS NOT NULL BUT IT SHOULD BE
                if (responseData == null) {
                    completion(Failure(APIError(internalError = "Unknown")))
                    return
                }
                
                //THIS PRINTS DefaultResponseResult(success=null, action=null, res=null) unfortunately 
                printLogs(responseData.toString())

                completion(Success(responseData))
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<T?>, t: Throwable) {
                printLogs("Failure")
                printLogs(call.request().toString())
                printLogs(t.toString())

                completion(Failure(APIError(internalError = "Failure")))
            }
        })
    }
```

DefaultResponseResult:

```
data class DefaultResponseResult(
    val success: String?,
    val action: String?,
    val res: String?
)
```

ErrorLog:

```
data class ErrorLog(
    val error: ErrorLogBody
)

data class ErrorLogBody(
    val authentication: String? = null
    //...
)
```

Request returns raw response as:

> {
> "error": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> 'ecyNabqKQjSPx-zn6Oshpd:APA91bFS7fGpnmnO_CiYfkQoF0Oo52ODWGRt-M...' for
> key 'PRIMARY'" }

And retrofit doesn't recognize it as error body because http code is 200 and that's something I can't change in the backend. I expect it to cast response.body() to null because data type is ErrorLog not DefaultResponseResult, instead it does this (from logcat console):

> DefaultResponseResult(success=null, action=null, res=null)

**How can I make it return null instead of DefaultResponseResult?**

Comment: what is json response suppose to look like?

Comment: json:
{
    "success": "Updated succ"..,
    "action"....
}

and object:
DefaultResponseResult(success="Updated successfully", action=null, res=null)

Comment: Did you test using Postman ?

Comment: Yes I did and the problem is not in the request but in retrofit. I expect it to return null when the response is not the same scheme as expected. The error response is not the problem.

Comment: Retrofit is working correctly. The API is not returning an error on the normal HTTP codes. It returns 200, which means that everything worked perfectly. However, you have some more logic built on top of that, where you can actually return an error for a 200 status code. But it is you responsability to handle this error case because Retrofit doesn't know anything about your data models.

Comment: But what if backend is not under my control. What then? I easily managed it with Swift.

Comment: You will have to parse the response data first. If it contains the error key, then it is an error and you could Gson to parse it automatically. If it doesn't, then you can parse as the class needed.